# Transfer settings from Listview to Detailview in Extbase (backPid)

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

After setting the flexform-settings I can use them on this page.
But after linking to another page using:

```
<f:link.action 
  pageUid="{settings.detailPid}"
  action="show"
  arguments="{object : object}">
    linktext
</f:link.action>
```

... I do not have access to this settings anymore - so I loose the setting for 'backPid'.
How can I use {settings.backPid} in Detailview on Detailpage?

**Edit: I would like to use the typoscript variables that are overwritten by flexformsettings.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass this settings into argument in your link viewhelper,
like

```
<f:link.action 
  pageUid="{settings.detailPid}"
  action="show"
  arguments="{object : object,backpid : settings.backpid}">
    linktext
</f:link.action>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That is no option because it sets the parameter into the url and it shouldn't.

Comment: then you have to do with session.

Comment: Can you Tell me how to do with Session?

Comment: There are different ways. The simplest would be for writing in the session

$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey("ses","key",$value)
and for reading values from the session

$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey("ses","key") ,
please check below link for more information,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440847/typo3-extbase-set-and-get-values-from-session