# How to keep values of filter object throughout a session

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've made a class for filtering a list of all appointments in my extbase extension - `AppointmentFilter` (Got that idea from [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html) tutorial with a demand object).

```
/**
 * action list
 * @param \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\AppointmentFilter $appointmentFilter
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction($appointmentFilter = null) {
    if ($appointmentFilter === null) {
        $appointmentFilter = new \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\AppointmentFilter();
    }
    $appointments = $this->appointmentRepository->findAppointmentsForList($appointmentFilter);

    $this->view->assignMultiple(array(
        'appointments' => $appointments,
        'appointmentFilter' => $appointmentFilter
    ));
}
```

So far it works fine but there's a problem when I choose another action like `edit` or `new` because I always pass the whole `AppointmentFilter` object to those actions in order to keep its values. If I don't do that and go back to `list` my controller will create a new filter with the default values again.
Now I have a lot of actions so it's really annoying to pass around that filter all the time.
Is there an easy way to make it stay the same while being logged-in after the user changes it once without passing it around in all actions or having to create a database table for it?
If so - how?

Comment: Maybe you can store those settings in a session? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440847/typo3-extbase-set-and-get-values-from-session

Comment: perfect, with the solution of that answer it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial at http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-backend-frontend-session-class/ , where Marcel Briefs has written an abstract implementation of the SessionHandler that lets you store and retrieve arrays as session data.

Then, if any arguments are given to your filter view, store your whole argument array as a key, or restore the whole argument array from the session data if none are given.

Comment: What is the advantage of that implementation instead of using 2 lines of code? - see accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440847/typo3-extbase-set-and-get-values-from-session
Is it the possibility of using it in the Backend as well?

Comment: The advantage is to have a clean class model that you can integrate into any controller and reuse without further hussle. I originally wanted to elaborate more and provide actual code, but my current Implementation too specific to be of any use.